# TypeError: Cannot read property 'setPageWithoutAnimation' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have recently updated react-native from 0.64.2 to 0.71.3
Also its other dependencies

But unfortunalty im facing the following Error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setPageWithoutAnimation' of undefined

This error is located at:
    in ViewPager (created by AnimatedComponent)
```

Also Attaching Image for Reference...

[image]

Looking forward for some help, could not find any solution so far.

Comment: Hello, did you find solution for it

Answer (score 1):

ViewPagerAndroid has been discontinued and removed from React Native, so you need to replace it with the react-native-pager-view library.

Here are the steps to make the necessary changes in react-native-scrollable-tab-view:

To remove ViewPagerAndroid from react-native-scrollable-tab-view, follow these steps:

1. Navigate to `node_modules/react-native-scrollable-tab-view/index.js`.
2. Remove references to ViewPagerAndroid.

Import the PagerView module from the react-native-pager-view package this way:

```
import PagerView from 'react-native-pager-view';
```

Replace the AnimatedViewPagerAndroid definition:

```
const AnimatedViewPagerAndroid = Platform.OS === 'android' ? Animated.createAnimatedComponent(PagerView) : undefined;
```

Remove the getNode() calls and modify the goToPage(pageNumber) function:

```
goToPage(pageNumber) {
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        const offset = pageNumber * this.state.containerWidth;
        if (this.scrollView) {
            this.scrollView.scrollTo({x: offset, y: 0, animated: !this.props.scrollWithoutAnimation});
        }
    } else {
        if (this.scrollView) {
            if (this.props.scrollWithoutAnimation) {
                this.scrollView.setPageWithoutAnimation(pageNumber);
            } else {
                this.scrollView.setPage(pageNumber);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This should correctly set up the use of PagerView instead of ViewPagerAndroid for the react-native-scrollable-tab-view module.

Patch-package should be used so that modifications persist in the node module code. This is particularly useful when we need to bypass a bug or make a modification to a library, but don't want to manually reapply these changes every time you run `npm install` or perform a build. Here is how to apply this to the project:

Install patch-package with npm or yarn:

```bash
npm i patch-package
```

or

```bash
yarn add patch-package
```

After making the necessary modifications in `node_modules/react-native-scrollable-tab-view/index.js`, it's time to create a patch. In the project's root directory, run:

```
npx patch-package react-native-scrollable-tab-view
```

This command will create a file in the project's patches/ directory that includes the changes made to react-native-scrollable-tab-view.

Finally, apply these patches automatically whenever `npm install` is run. To do this, add the following to the scripts section of your `package.json` file:

```
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "patch-package"
}
```

Now, whenever you run `npm install` or generate a 'build', the modifications to react-native-scrollable-tab-view will be automatically applied, making them persistent in builds and installations.

For more detailed information, check out the npm page for patch-package at: https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package